# what is jquery plugin that www.about.me use?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

is there any body who knows what javascript plugin that about.me use ? especially when editing a profile .. check this out: [www.about.me](http://www.about.me)

[image]

[image: aboutme profile editor]

My question:

i want to know every jquery plugin that aboutme use. i like the dialog box tabed style ..is there anybody who know about the plugin about.me use ?

i tried to see the source code, inpecting the element in the about.me site. but i dont know what is the jquery plugin/ javascript that aboutme use.

Comment: If you've already inspected the source code and haven't found anything, what makes you think they use a jQuery plugin at all? Maybe they wrote it themselves.

Comment: Have a look at the bottom of the jQuery file for the extensions: https://gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net/802659/production96/js/jquery_plus.min.js?ts=1324426183267. And at this file for the powering engine: https://gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net/802659/production96/js/aboutme.js?ts=1324426183267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see all their custom code is stored in the [aboutme.js](https://gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net/802659/production96/js/aboutme.js?ts=1324426183267) file. It doesn't seem their code organized as the jQuery plugins. However you can find some plugins in jquery_plus.min.js. They are:

1. http://www.whitespace-creative.com/jquery/jnice/
2. jQuery Form Plugin
3. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
4. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/
5. http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Comment: then my next question is .. is there any software that makes the javascript source become more neat and easy to understand ? the aboutme.js is really complex structure.. unorganized...

Comment: well after discover some sites i found jsfiddle.net i like the "tidy up" button :D anyway ... Tq for ur suggestion...